# How are urls like this created? (googlevideo.com)

Tags: url, redirect

```
https://r9---sn-a5m7lnel.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=c815cbfeddf16cb0&itag=18&source=webdrive&begin=0&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-a5m7lnel&ms=nxu&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLmxheDE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=19&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1458651337361788&mt=1460326877&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=8&expire=1460355737&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,mime,lm​t&signature=6BC2EA4F643071A5FACCFD9413B48FC1DCB53710.387DCD60FD8900AE04010A993​EDFF340D2A67406&key=ck2
```

This URL is a "direct" link to a video. I'm unsure how these URLs are handled and how they came to be. I assumed it was from Google Drive or Google Photos, but I can't seem to get the same URL format from a quick video I uploaded onto Google Drive/Photo.

Does anyone know how this URL is generated and maintained?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your normal video link–URL with the format https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXID/view/, you can right click twice in a row and click "Copy Video Address", and it will get you the link in that format.

Note that these links are temporary and IP-locked, so it won't work forever or on another device.